# TypeError: 'dict_keys' object is not callable

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda, max, min

I have used the below  program to get the maximum and minimum value in a dictionary. But, there is an type error.

I am running the below code on Jupyter notebook and getting the type error as the 'dict.keys' object is not callable. same code runs successfully on the pycharm.

Please advise me what changes should I make so that the code runs successfully on the jupyter notebook?
what is wrong in my code? Code run on JupyterNBcode run on Pycharm successfully[image][image]

Comment: from your screenshot, looks like its finding for "dict_keys" object. are you sure you have saved the changes before running. or try saving or reloading and run it again.

Comment: if jupyter is the case, you can also Restart and Run Kernel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested your program in Jupyter Notebook and the code is working just fine. Maybe you check for any typos. Hope this help

[Code snippet run on jupyter notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7o5V.png)

Comment: Thank you.. the code is running fine on the new page ..

Answer (score 0):

Yup I can run your code perfectly too. Please try to simplify it like below.
It looks better too.

```
my_dict = {'x':500, 'y':5874, 'z': 560}

key_max = max(my_dict, key = my_dict.get)

key_min = min(my_dict, key = my_dict.get)

print('Maximum Value: ',my_dict[key_max])

print('Minimum Value: ',my_dict[key_min])
```